# android oreo , /system, /data and /sdcard for media

Tags: file-system, 8.1-oreo

I am in need of a new mobile and the new kid on the block is Android 8.0 .  From what little I could garner it seems there are three partitions by default which happen in an android phone. I come from unix/linux background so would be using comparison from a linux layout

/system = / (or root) where all applications/binaries will be installed . ext4

/data = (probably /home but not sure as that is unclear.) ext4

/sdcard = something akin to /home/$username or better yet /media but (fuse fileystem FAT32 or something equivalent.

I know that in android 6.0 users could copy and paste media/music etc. from their system to the mobile phone and back. This feature was taken away in 7.0 series. Is this back ?

Also can somebody share if my comparison is correct or incorrect. I am not sure exactly as to what /data is used for.

I don't see the concept of swap, does it take from / . I do know that most phones do come with RAM 8GB
 and en onwards
.

Comment: As you reference SD card, see my comments to a somewhat related question: [What are the technical reasons behind the difficulty in using an SD card with Android 4 or later?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/202210/3573)

Answer (score 2):

The root directory `/` is a concept that's found on Android as well. It is recreated anew during each boot, and hosts `*.init.rc` directives read by Android every time it boots.

---

The `/system` partition is something special: system binaries live under `/system/bin` and `/system/xbin`, so this is probably what made you compare this partition to `/bin`, but there's much more.

`/system/app` and `/system/priv-app`, for example, store the apps preloaded on your device by the OEM, while the `/system/framework` and `/system/lib` are core to Android, because they house `.jar` classes and `.so` libraries that are shared between apps.

---

The comparison between `/data` and `/home` is quite accurate but, once again, there are some differences. Here, you can find all sorts of things, from apps you installed yourself to a listing of the access points you connected to, along with their WPA keys in plaintext.

Of particular importance are: `/data/app`, which houses the `.apk` files of your installed apps; `/data/data`, which stores the apps' private data; `/data/misc/wifi`, where access point data can be found; `/data/system`, which is perhaps the most important of the bunch, as it houses the `packages.xml` file, in charge of keeping trace of every app and permission in your device.

Last but not least, we have `/data/media/0`, which is the real internal storage of the current user. This is the directory that gets isolated from the others via FUSE, making it akin to the `/home/$username` directory on Linux, as you noticed. There are a number of symlinks that point to this restricted directory, the most known being the ill-named `/sdcard` and `/storage/emulated/0`.

It's worth mentioning that the entirety of the directories I mentioned cannot be accessed without root permissions, aside from `/sdcard` and `/storage/emulated/0`.

---

To conclude, I'll spend a few words on the concepts of swap and data transfer.

Swap, as far as I know, is not a concept that belongs to Android; support for it, along with zRAM, can be added via the use of a customized kernel.

File transfer from a computer to an Android device has always been possible, if I remember correctly. Android uses the MTP interface to restrict the directories the computer can access, though, so you'll need the necessary backends. Moreover, only `/sdcard` and, optionally, an external SD card can be accessed.